# math.Mod in Go returns integer part instead of floating-point remainder

Tags: floating-point, go, division, modulo

Golang's **math.Mod(10, 4)** returns 2 -- ie. the integer part of division result 2.5 -- but shouldn't it be "the floating point remainder", that is, 0.5?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The result is correct. [math.Mod](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Mod) returns the remainder, which really is 2 in this case. It's equivalent to the % operator, but for floating point numbers.

Comment: Thanks... guess I got both my memory of the modulo operator *and* my understanding of "remainder" backwards then!

Answer (score -1):

if you're looking for the value after the decimal place after doing floating point division, as I understand, you would want something like this:

```
double A = 10.0;
double B = 4.0;
double divResult = A / B;
double fractional = divResult % 1.0;
//prints "10.0 / 4.0 fractional remainder: 0.5"
System.out.printf("%f / %f fractional remainder: %f", A , B, fractional);
```